# How to create new folder on POP3 protocol

Tags: java, protocols, jakarta-mail, pop3

I want to create a folder with the name "Spam" by using Javamail Api, but I'm not allowed to create any folder on POP3 protocol. What should I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use IMAP or some other protocol that supports folders.