# php pop3 email folder not created

Tags: php, email, pop3

I have hosted a domain and it has a pop3 email server. I have successfully connected to it but I am unable to create new folders for a particular account.

Code:

```
$server="{localhost:110/pop3}";

$username="username";

$password="password";

$mbox=imap_open($server,$username,$password);
if($mbox)
{
if(!imap_createmailbox($mbox,"{localhost:110/pop3}DRAFTS"))
{  
echo imap_last_error();
}
  else
  echo "mailbox created!";
}
```

The createmailbox is throwing false and no error is printed by last_error() function.
Is something wrong with my code or Should we do it differently for POP3 accounts. I have went php manual and read many articles but could not get answer. Please advice!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create new folder on POP3 protocol](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500361/how-to-create-new-folder-on-pop3-protocol)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think POP3 supports this at all - it's just designed for retrieving mail, not organising it on the server...

[See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500361/how-to-create-new-folder-on-pop3-protocol).